# Tomcat/MySQL/Java servlet application getting 500 error after some hours of inactivity (using JNDI Connection Pool)

Tags: mysql, tomcat, servlets

I have written a Java Servlet/JSP web app that uses MySQL to hold the login authentication. The web container is Tomcat 7.0.47, and I'm using JNDI connection pooling for the database connectivity. I've carefully configured the `<Resource...>` tags in my Tomcat's context.xml and during the day when there is plenty of activity the application's login functionality never fails. But after an overnight break, the very first login attempt very often throws a 500 error in the browser. On the second attempt and subsequent attempts in the same day, the login succeeds.

**I've tried:**

1: updating the MySQL server to the latest version (running in Windows Server 2008)

2: Updating the mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar (the latest at time of writing)

3: removing the mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar file from the build path (as I've already included it in the Tomcat lib directory)

4: Added the attribute `closeMethod = "close"` to the  tag in Tomcat context.xml

5: Added attribute `minIdle = "1"` to the  tag in Tomcat context.xml

6: I have `removeAbandoned = "true"` configured in context.xml

7: Changing all my application code to Java 7's try-with-resources to guarantee closing of all resources in the application code

(4, 5 and 6 are just post-Googling stabs in the dark really, and they didn't work)

Every morning I'm the first to log in to my application: I get the 500, then for the rest of the day, everything is fine. I've been looking at this for weeks now but am out of ideas!

Comment: It sounds as though the connections in the database connection pool have died overnight (maybe some network gateway times them out after a certain period of inactivity). Could you post the datasource configuration from the context.xml? Some datasources can be configured to perform periodic testing of connections which should keep the connections alive overnight.

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for your answer - here is one of my resource tags from context.xml:                                                          <Resource name="jdbc/login" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" minIdle = "1" maxWait="10000" removeAbandoned="true" logAbandoned="true" username="notRealUser" password="notRealPassword" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"              url="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/login"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following two attributes to your datasource configuration.

```
testOnBorrow="true"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
```

The first, `testOnBorrow` tells the datasource to validate the connection before handing it back to the application. The second, `validationQuery` is the SQL which is used to validate the connection. Note the SQL of `SELECT 1` is a valid value for MySQL databases.

That should hopefully prevent the datasource from handing back a dud connection to the application. The updated `<Resource>` tag should then look like the following:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/login" 
          auth="Container" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          maxActive="100" 
          maxIdle="30" 
          minIdle = "1" 
          maxWait="10000" 
          removeAbandoned="true" 
          logAbandoned="true" 
          username="notRealUser" 
          password="notRealPassword" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/login"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
```

Comment: thanks again Will! - I've added these two attributes and I'll see how it goes on Monday morning (next opportunity). I'll post back the result then.

Comment: Don't forget after adding the two attributes you'll need to restart Tomcat for the change to get picked up. Look forward to hearing back.

Comment: Hey Will - that worked a dream! Awesome solution - I have wasted many hours troubleshooting this so, sincerely, thank you! So far I've tested it two days running now and each morning my app has logged in perfectly! Yes I figured that about restarting the Tomcat. Thanks for your help (would upvote; but not enough rep yet)

Comment: Excellent - glad that sorted it